# New to Xamarin and needing to add Signature Pad to ToolBox VS 2015

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

Hi I am developing an app I need for school and have been following tutorials quite successfully. I do need to have a signature pad within the app and I see that Xamarin released a package for it. I see it here:

https://components.xamarin.com/view/signature-pad

I am not sure how to get this into my VS toolbox so that I can use it? My toolbox includes all the buttons/textview/etc. What file to I need to but this into? I am running the latest Xamarin on Visual Studio 2015 and am developing an Android application. I am very new to this so please a little "spoon-feeding" may be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a component in Xamarin Android (Visual Studio)-

1. Right click on the '**Component**' from solution explorer.
2. Click '**Get More Component**' and log in using your xamarin account.
3. Search for desired component and click install. After installing **rebuild** the solution. Now you will see your installed component in toolbox.